# emitting Fluxes on demand using Flex.generate()

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, project-reactor

I want to poll from a MongoDB collection every second and emit the results onto a continuous stream.  The ReactiveMongoTemplate provides a Flux that publishes results from a query, but closes when it is done.

```
@Service
public class MongoPoller implements ApplicationRunner {
    private static final FindAndModifyOptions findAndModifyOptions = FindAndModifyOptions.options()
            .upsert(false)
            .returnNew(false);

    @Autowired
    private ReactiveMongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
        System.out.println("Start MongoPoller");
        Mono<DeleteResult> remove = mongoTemplate.remove(new Query(), Person.class).log();
        remove.block();

        Flux<Person> insertPeople = Flux.range(0, 5)
                .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(750))
                .flatMap(i -> {
                    Person p = new Person(null, "James " + i, "1 Main St", "UNPROCESSED", 0, null);
                    return mongoTemplate.insert(p);
                });
        insertPeople.subscribe(p -> {
            System.out.printf("Inserted %s%n", p.getName());
        });

        Flux<Flux<Person>> personFlux = Flux.generate((SynchronousSink<Flux<Person>> synchronousSink) -> {
            Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("status").is("UNPROCESSED")).limit(2);
            Flux<Person> people = mongoTemplate.find(query, Person.class);
            people.count().subscribe(c -> System.out.printf("Pulled %s documents from Mongo%n", c));
            synchronousSink.next(people);
        }).delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(1000L));

            personFlux.delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
                    .concatMap(Function.identity())
                    .flatMap(p -> {
                        Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("_id").is(p.getId())
                                .and("status").is("UNPROCESSED");
                        Query findQuery = Query.query(criteria);
                        Update update = BasicUpdate.update("status", "PROCESSED")
                                .inc("version", 1)
                                .addToSet("threadNames", Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        return mongoTemplate.findAndModify(findQuery, update, findAndModifyOptions, Person.class);
                    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(3, 3, "test")).subscribe(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

This seems to work:

```
Pulled 0 documents from Mongo
Inserted James 0
Pulled 1 documents from Mongo
Inserted James 1
Pulled 2 documents from Mongo
Person(id=65ce9a86816f470d8f3d8796, name=James 0, address=1 Main St, status=UNPROCESSED, version=0, threadNames=null)
Person(id=65ce9a86816f470d8f3d8797, name=James 1, address=1 Main St, status=UNPROCESSED, version=0, threadNames=null)
Inserted James 2
Inserted James 3
Pulled 2 documents from Mongo
Person(id=65ce9a88816f470d8f3d8799, name=James 3, address=1 Main St, status=UNPROCESSED, version=0, threadNames=null)
Person(id=65ce9a87816f470d8f3d8798, name=James 2, address=1 Main St, status=UNPROCESSED, version=0, threadNames=null)
Inserted James 4
Pulled 0 documents from Mongo
Person(id=65ce9a89816f470d8f3d879a, name=James 4, address=1 Main St, status=UNPROCESSED, version=0, threadNames=null)
Pulled 0 documents from Mongo
Pulled 0 documents from Mongo
Pulled 0 documents from Mongo
Pulled 0 documents from Mongo
...
```

It will then continue to poll and emit more data as it is inserting into the collection.

My question is if using Flux.generate() to create a Flux of Fluxes is a bad idea.  I like that fact that Flux.generate() works on demand, so that the query only run once the subscriber is ready for more data.  When the consumer is ready for more it simply emits a new flux and then concatMaps it.

Am I setting myself up for problems later on?